# Alignment of tools for DataTables

Tags: css, datatables

I need to know how to align some of the tools for DataTables, especially the print option.  It shows up like this:

[image: Print is not in line with search]

The parameters are like this:

```
 $("#tblNewUsers").dataTable({
        bProcessing: true,
        sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("GetAllNewUsers")',
        bJQueryUI: true,
        sProcessing: "<img src='~/Images/spinner.gif' />",
        dom: 'Tlf<"clear">rtip',
        bAutoWidth: false,
        "oLanguage": {
            sEmptyTable: "There are no New Users at this time"
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sWidth": "1%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", sClass: "smallfonts" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", sClass: "smallFonts" }
        ],
        tableTools: {
            "sSwfPath": "../../Scripts/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends": "print",
                    "bShowAll": true
                }
            ]

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move entire table tools toolbar move T letter in the initialization. Example that pushes entire toolbar at the end is:

```
"sDom": '<"clear">lfrtipT'
```

You cannot reconfigure DataTables to move only print button, but you can use standard JQuery to take button with class "DTTT_button_print" to some new position.

For Example: Move to new element

```
var printButton = $(".DTTT_button_print").detach();
$("#newPosition").append( pdfButton );
```

Or add CSS:

```
$(".DTTT_button_print").css("top","-20px");
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/jevtw2g4/11/